# Link to data url doesn't open until I hit return in url bar

Tags: java, browser, data-uri

I have a chunk of html that I want to render in another window when somebody clicks on a link (embedded in some text that comes from the back-end) in the browser. So in the Java back-end, I base64 encode it and put it into the text that's being sent to the front end:

```
String encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(resourceRecord.getHtml().getBytes());
                    a.attr("href", "data:text/html;base64," + encoded)
                            .attr("target", "_blank")
                            .attr("rel", "nofollow");
```

And when the text is rendered, I see a blue underlined link that looks like this in the web inspector:
[image]

So far so good. Unfortunately, when I click the link, it just opened a new blank tab. In both Firefox and Chrome, if I click on the address bar in that new tab, it shows the data url in the address bar, and if I hit return the expected html is rendered.

How can I make that html actually render without the "click in the address bar and hit return" step? Or is it even possible?

**Update** Added a Content Security Policy with `navigate-to 'self' https: http: data:` and that didn't help. I also tried *not* base64 encoding because I read one site that said that Chrome was restricting top level data urls only for base64 encoding, but that didn't help, and other sources talked about restricting it for all data urls. Every solution I saw involved opening a window and doing a write into it, rather than using an `<a>` tag, so I'm coming to the conclusion that this just isn't possible.

Comment: Do you see any logging messages in the browser console related to the `Content-Security-Policy` header? https://content-security-policy.com/

Comment: @dpr not on Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: @dpr, I take that back. If I remove the `target="_blank"`, I can see the CSP error: `Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL: data:text/html;base64,PHA+TG9yZW0gaXB...`

Comment: You have to allow loading data from data-uris in the header... take a look at https://content-security-policy.com/ there are plenty of examples.

Comment: Copied the CSP from prod into dev (because dev didn't have one), added `navigate-to 'self' https: http: data:` and I'm still getting the same error.